# Library dependency coming out of nowhere

Tags: linker

I'm building on a HP-UX ia64 system. During building, I'm getting an error

```
ld: Can't find dependent library "libnnz10.so"
```

Nowhere in my makefile do I link with this library. This library is there in the directory /databases/oracle10.2.0_64BIT/lib. I'm having two source files ora8ibulk.cpp and ora8idplinit.cpp. The commands issued during the build are

```
aCC -DUSE_NEW_IOSTREAMS -AA -mt -z -ext +w -Wc,-ansi_for_scope,on +W302 +W392 +We400 +W2009 +W2193 +W2261 +W4227 +W4255  -DACE_HAS_THREADS -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=199506L -DHPUX_VERS=1100 -DACE_LACKS_PRAGMA_ONCE +DD64 +DSitanium2 +O2 +Ofltacc  +DD64 +DSitanium2  -DPM_64BIT -DFD_SETSIZE=60000 -D__ACE_INLINE__ -DRW_NO_STL -DRW_NO_BOOL -DINFA_PREFIX -DUNIX -DHPUX_IPF -I. -I/export/home/builds/Debug_9.5.0/mercury/native/default/ORACLE/10.1_A/HP-UX.IPF.64/rdbms/demo -I/export/home/builds/Debug_9.5.0/mercury/native/default/ORACLE/10.1_A/HP-UX.IPF.64/rdbms/public -I/export/home/builds/Debug_9.5.0/mercury/native/default/ORACLE/10.1_A/HP-UX.IPF.64/network/public -I/export/home/builds/Debug_9.5.0/mercury/native/default/ORACLE/10.1_A/HP-UX.IPF.64/plsql/public -I/export/home/builds/Debug_9.5.0/mercury/ws/platform/dbadapters/src/pmorabulk/include -I/export/home/builds/Debug_9.5.0/mercury/ws/platform/dbadapters/include -I/export/home/builds/Debug_9.5.0/mercury/native/default/base/409/HP-UX.IPF.64-DEVEL/include -I/export/home/builds/Debug_9.5.0/mercury/native/default/cmnutils/409/HP-UX.IPF.64-DEVEL/include -I/export/home/builds/Debug_9.5.0/mercury/native/default/ICU/3.2.1_D/HP-UX.IPF.64/include -I/export/home/builds/Debug_9.5.0/mercury/native/default/ACE/5.4.7_B/HP-UX.IPF.64 -I/export/home/builds/Debug_9.5.0/mercury/native/default/STLPORT_INCLUDE/4.6.2_A/HP-UX.IPF.64 -I/export/home/builds/Debug_9.5.0/mercury/native/default/STLPORT_INCLUDE/4.6.2_A/HP-UX.IPF.64/stlport -I/opt/aCC/include/iostream \
    -c /export/home/builds/Debug_9.5.0/mercury/ws/platform/dbadapters/src/pmorabulk/ora8ibulk.cpp -o ../../target/pmorabulk/tmp/HP-UX.IPF.64.r/ora8ibulk.o

aCC -DUSE_NEW_IOSTREAMS -AA -mt -z -ext +w -Wc,-ansi_for_scope,on +W302 +W392 +We400 +W2009 +W2193 +W2261 +W4227 +W4255  -DACE_HAS_THREADS -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=199506L -DHPUX_VERS=1100 -DACE_LACKS_PRAGMA_ONCE +DD64 +DSitanium2 +O2 +Ofltacc  +DD64 +DSitanium2  -DPM_64BIT -DFD_SETSIZE=60000 -D__ACE_INLINE__ -DRW_NO_STL -DRW_NO_BOOL -DINFA_PREFIX -DUNIX -DHPUX_IPF -I. -I/export/home/builds/Debug_9.5.0/mercury/native/default/ORACLE/10.1_A/HP-UX.IPF.64/rdbms/demo -I/export/home/builds/Debug_9.5.0/mercury/native/default/ORACLE/10.1_A/HP-UX.IPF.64/rdbms/public -I/export/home/builds/Debug_9.5.0/mercury/native/default/ORACLE/10.1_A/HP-UX.IPF.64/network/public -I/export/home/builds/Debug_9.5.0/mercury/native/default/ORACLE/10.1_A/HP-UX.IPF.64/plsql/public -I/export/home/builds/Debug_9.5.0/mercury/ws/platform/dbadapters/src/pmorabulk/include -I/export/home/builds/Debug_9.5.0/mercury/ws/platform/dbadapters/include -I/export/home/builds/Debug_9.5.0/mercury/native/default/base/409/HP-UX.IPF.64-DEVEL/include -I/export/home/builds/Debug_9.5.0/mercury/native/default/cmnutils/409/HP-UX.IPF.64-DEVEL/include -I/export/home/builds/Debug_9.5.0/mercury/native/default/ICU/3.2.1_D/HP-UX.IPF.64/include -I/export/home/builds/Debug_9.5.0/mercury/native/default/ACE/5.4.7_B/HP-UX.IPF.64 -I/export/home/builds/Debug_9.5.0/mercury/native/default/STLPORT_INCLUDE/4.6.2_A/HP-UX.IPF.64 -I/export/home/builds/Debug_9.5.0/mercury/native/default/STLPORT_INCLUDE/4.6.2_A/HP-UX.IPF.64/stlport -I/opt/aCC/include/iostream \
    -c /export/home/builds/Debug_9.5.0/mercury/ws/platform/dbadapters/src/pmorabulk/ora8idplinit.cpp -o ../../target/pmorabulk/tmp/HP-UX.IPF.64.r/ora8idplinit.o

aCC  +DD64 +DSitanium2 -b -Wl,+s -z -mt  ../../target/pmorabulk/tmp/HP-UX.IPF.64.r/ora8ibulk.o ../../target/pmorabulk/tmp/HP-UX.IPF.64.r/ora8idplinit.o \
         -o ../../target/bin/HP-UX.IPF.64.r/libpmorablk.sl \
         -L/export/home/builds/Debug_9.5.0/mercury/native/default/ORACLE/10.1_A/HP-UX.IPF.64/lib -lclntsh \

ld: Can't find dependent library "libnnz10.so"
```

From where does this dependency on libnnz10.so come in? Please help before I shoot myself.

Answer (score 1):

Something lists libnnz10.so as a library (as you have guessed).. To find it run 'ldd' against the libraries you're including, keep on doing that until you find out what needs libnnz10.so.

Comment: You are right, I'm linking against libclntsh.so and this library requires libnnz.so. But both of these libraries are found in /databases/oracle10.2.0_64BIT/lib, and this directory is there in my $SHLIB_PATH variable. Then why can't it load libnnz.so?

Comment: You're not specifying -L/databases/oracle10.2.0_64BIT/lib to the compiler. SHLIB_PATH (I would presume is similar to LD_LIBRARY_PATH on Linux, or DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH on OSX) -- will only tell executing programs where to look for libraries. Your compiler will only look in directories in its sys root or that you explicitly tell it to look in.